# How can I tell Firewall to allow incoming connections for Python.app running Django

Tags: macos, python, firewall

Each time I run my Django development server, I get a dialog to allow incoming connections.

No matter what I do :

- Click Allow in the dialog box
- Add to the Firewall via the OS X GUI
  (both real and venv python executables are allowed, and also the
  Python.app
- Self-sign the executable (see http://darklaunch.com/2014/02/02/fix-do-you-want-the-application-python-to-accept-incoming-network-connections)

OS X still systematically ask me to allow incoming connection.

It's not just annoying, it's impossible to work with my IDE which restart the dev server after each code change.

[image]

I have to either turn off the firewall, or change my IDE configuration, both are bad solutions.

**How can I permanently add the script in my firewall allowed apps?**

I'm running Maverick 10.9.4

Answer (score 2):

Signing the python application, using the instruction in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19688841/add-python-to-os-x-firewall-options), worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually configure the firewall to unblock a port (i.e. 8080).

You'll need to open `/etc/pf.conf` in a text editor and add:

`pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8080`

to the end of the file (for port 8080, adjust to suit your needs).

Then restart your computer.

If that doesn't work run:

$ `sudo pfctl -vnf /etc/pf.conf`

to see if you get an error. If so fix.

Then restart again.

Should work.

Comment: I added `pass in proto tcp from any to any port 8000` to  `/etc/pf.conf` and restarted. Nothing changed. I don't see any error when using `pfctl`.

Comment: What IDE are you using? It seems from you original message that it is play an integral part of this equation.

Comment: I am using `PyCharm Professional Edition`